# Adding CSS to a window.open created in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, window.open, on-the-fly

The goal of my code is to create a resume builder using HTML, CSS and JavaScript. Once the user "clicks" create resume, a new window should open with the content enter styled in a resume format of my choosing. I cannot use HTML to style the resume.

The issue I am having is my styling will not populate in an on-the-fly created with JavaScript. At this point, I have only tried to center the first name (I am testing to see if my code is correct). I am not receiving any errors, however, nothing is changing. I am not sure if it is because I am only doing the first name and I need to format the other content, or if I am actually coding something wrong.

I have created the HTML for the users to enter their information and the JavaScript to populate the information. No errors!

I added a function to center align the firstName. No errors! However, nothing happens!?

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>WEB-115 Final Project</title>
        <style>
            body {
                background-color: peru;
            }

            h1 {
                text-align: center;
                padding: 60px;
                background: forestgreen;
                font-size: 30px;
            }
        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <h1>Build Your Resume</h1>

        <form>
            <div id="myinfo">
            <h2>Personal Information:</h2>
            <label>Enter your first name:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="firstName"><br><br>
            <label>Enter your last name:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="lastName"><br><br>
            <label>Enter your preferred name:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="preName"><br><br>
            <label>Enter your email address:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="email"><br><br>
            <label>Enter your phone number:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="number"><br><br>
            <label>Enter your state:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="state"><br><br>
            <label>Enter your city:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="city"><br><br>
            <label>Enter your zipcode:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="zip"><br><br>
            <p>About Me</p>
            <textarea rows="15" cols="33" id="aboutMe">Tell us about the position you are looking for!</textarea><br><br>
            </div>

            <div id="myEdu">
            <h2>Enter Educational History:</h2>
            <label>Start Date:</label>
            <input type="date" id="eduStart"><br><br>
            <label>End Date:</label>
            <input type="date" id="eduEnd"><br><br>
            <label>Name of school:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="school"><br><br>
            <label>Degree type:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="degree"><br><br>
            <label>Field of study:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="major"><br><br>
            </div>
            
            <div id="myJob">
            <h2>Enter job information:</h2>
            <label>Start Date:</label>
            <input type="date" id="jobStart"><br><br>
            <label>End Date:</label>
            <input type="date" id="jobEnd"><br><br>
            
            
            <p>Position Details:</p>
            <textarea rows="5" cols="33" id="details">Click Here!</textarea><br><br>
            </div>

            <div id="extra">
            <h2>Please Enter Your Skills:</h2>
            <textarea rows="15" cols="33" id="skills">Click Here!</textarea><br><br>

            <h2>Links:</h2>

            <p>Please provide links to any websites or blogs.</p>
            <textarea rows="15" cols="33" id="links">Click Here!</textarea><br><br>
            </div>

            <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Create Resume">

        </form>

        <script src="projectJS.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
/*style*/
function myFunction () {
    let fName = document.getElementById("firstName");
    fName.style.textAlign = "center";
}
/*button*/
document.getElementById("btnSubmit").addEventListener('click',myWindow)
    /*function to create resume*/
    function myWindow()
    {
        /*get HTML first name*/
        fName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
        /*get HTML last name*/
        lName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
        /*get HTML preferred name*/
        pName = document.getElementById("preName").value;
        /*get HTML email address*/
        eAddress = document.getElementById("email").value;
        /*get HTML phone number*/
        phoneNum = document.getElementById("number").value;
        /*get HTML state*/
        stateAdd = document.getElementById("state").value;
        /*get HTML city*/
        cityAdd = document.getElementById("city").value;
        /*get HTML zip code*/
        zipCode = document.getElementById("zip").value;
        /*get HTML about me*/
        about = document.getElementById("aboutMe").value;
        /*get HTML Edu start date*/
        schoolStart = document.getElementById("eduStart").value;
        /*get HTML Edu end date*/
        schoolEnd = document.getElementById("eduEnd").value;
        /*get HTML School*/
        schoolName = document.getElementById("school").value;
        /*get HTML degree type*/
        degreeType = document.getElementById("degree").value;
        /*get HTML major*/
        fieldStudy = document.getElementById("major").value;
        /*get HTML job start date*/
        jStart = document.getElementById("jobStart").value;
        /*get HTML job end date*/
        jEnd = document.getElementById("jobEnd").value;
        /*get HTML job details*/
        jobDetails = document.getElementById("details").value;
        /*get HTML skills*/
        mySkills = document.getElementById("skills").value;
         /*get HTML links*/
        webPage = document.getElementById("links").value;
        myText = ("<html>\n<head>\n<title>WEB-115 Final Project</title>\n</head>\n<body>");
        myText += (fName);
        myText += (lName);
        myText += (pName);
        myText += (eAddress);
        myText += (phoneNum);
        myText += (stateAdd);
        myText += (cityAdd);
        myText += (zipCode);
        myText += (about);
        myText += (schoolStart);
        myText += (schoolEnd);
        myText += (schoolName);
        myText += (degreeType);
        myText += (fieldStudy);
        myText += (jStart);
        myText += (jEnd);
        myText += (jobDetails);
        myText += (mySkills);
        myText += (webPage);
        myText += ("</body>\n</html>");
    
        flyWindow = window.open('about:blank','myPop','width=400,height=200,left=200,top=200');
        flyWindow.document.write(myText);
    }
```

Comment: "I added a function to center align the firstName",  myFunction(), sorry my eyes playing tricks on me, don't see how the myFunction() is triggered in the code provided.

Comment: If you want to add styles to your new document, then you'll have to treat it like any other document. Add a `<link rel="stylesheet" href="yourstyles.css"/>` tag to it so the document knows where to get the styles from.

Comment: "I cannot use HTML to style the resume." why not? If you can't use HTML then you also can't use CSS. Please explain the reason of this limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can check style works or not with a file or an inline style:

```
  // If you use css file style
  // myText = (`<html>\n<head>\n<title>WEB-115 Final Project</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles1.css">\n</head>\n<body>`);
  // Else if you use inline style
  let style = `body {
    color: blue;
  }
  .text-center {
    text-align: center;
  }
  `;
  myText = (`<html>\n<head>\n<title>WEB-115 Final Project</title><style>${style}</style>\n</head>\n<body>`);
  myText += `<div class="text-center">${fName}</div>`;
```

Then, if you want to use a function to do this job, you can control it by set a global flyWindow variable like my way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>WEB-115 Final Project</title>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: peru;
    }

    h1 {
      text-align: center;
      padding: 60px;
      background: forestgreen;
      font-size: 30px;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <h1>Build Your Resume</h1>

  <form>
    <div id="myinfo">
      <h2>Personal Information:</h2>
      <label>Enter your first name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="firstName"><br><br>
      <label>Enter your last name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="lastName"><br><br>
      <label>Enter your preferred name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="preName"><br><br>
      <label>Enter your email address:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="email"><br><br>
      <label>Enter your phone number:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="number"><br><br>
      <label>Enter your state:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="state"><br><br>
      <label>Enter your city:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="city"><br><br>
      <label>Enter your zipcode:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="zip"><br><br>
      <p>About Me</p>
      <textarea rows="15" cols="33" id="aboutMe">Tell us about the position you are looking for!</textarea><br><br>
    </div>

    <div id="myEdu">
      <h2>Enter Educational History:</h2>
      <label>Start Date:</label>
      <input type="date" id="eduStart"><br><br>
      <label>End Date:</label>
      <input type="date" id="eduEnd"><br><br>
      <label>Name of school:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="school"><br><br>
      <label>Degree type:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="degree"><br><br>
      <label>Field of study:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="major"><br><br>
    </div>

    <div id="myJob">
      <h2>Enter job information:</h2>
      <label>Start Date:</label>
      <input type="date" id="jobStart"><br><br>
      <label>End Date:</label>
      <input type="date" id="jobEnd"><br><br>

      <p>Position Details:</p>
      <textarea rows="5" cols="33" id="details">Click Here!</textarea><br><br>
    </div>

    <div id="extra">
      <h2>Please Enter Your Skills:</h2>
      <textarea rows="15" cols="33" id="skills">Click Here!</textarea><br><br>

      <h2>Links:</h2>

      <p>Please provide links to any websites or blogs.</p>
      <textarea rows="15" cols="33" id="links">Click Here!</textarea><br><br>
    </div>

    <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Create Resume">

  </form>

  <!-- <script src="projectJS.js"></script> -->
  <script>
    /*button*/
    document.getElementById("btnSubmit").addEventListener('click', myWindow)
    /*function to create resume*/
    function myWindow() {
      /*get HTML first name*/
      fName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
      /*get HTML last name*/
      lName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
      /*get HTML preferred name*/
      pName = document.getElementById("preName").value;
      /*get HTML email address*/
      eAddress = document.getElementById("email").value;
      /*get HTML phone number*/
      phoneNum = document.getElementById("number").value;
      /*get HTML state*/
      stateAdd = document.getElementById("state").value;
      /*get HTML city*/
      cityAdd = document.getElementById("city").value;
      /*get HTML zip code*/
      zipCode = document.getElementById("zip").value;
      /*get HTML about me*/
      about = document.getElementById("aboutMe").value;
      /*get HTML Edu start date*/
      schoolStart = document.getElementById("eduStart").value;
      /*get HTML Edu end date*/
      schoolEnd = document.getElementById("eduEnd").value;
      /*get HTML School*/
      schoolName = document.getElementById("school").value;
      /*get HTML degree type*/
      degreeType = document.getElementById("degree").value;
      /*get HTML major*/
      fieldStudy = document.getElementById("major").value;
      /*get HTML job start date*/
      jStart = document.getElementById("jobStart").value;
      /*get HTML job end date*/
      jEnd = document.getElementById("jobEnd").value;
      /*get HTML job details*/
      jobDetails = document.getElementById("details").value;
      /*get HTML skills*/
      mySkills = document.getElementById("skills").value;
      /*get HTML links*/
      webPage = document.getElementById("links").value;
      // If you directly use a css file style
      // myText = (`<html>\n<head>\n<title>WEB-115 Final Project</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles1.css">\n</head>\n<body>`);
      
      // Else if you use inline style
      // let style = `body {
      //   color: blue;
      // }
      // .text-center {
      //   text-align: center;
      // }
      // `;
      // myText = (`<html>\n<head>\n<title>WEB-115 Final Project</title><style>${style}</style>\n</head>\n<body>`);
      // myText += `<div class="text-center">${fName}</div>`;
      
      // Else if you want to set it by a function
      myText = (`<html>\n<head>\n<title>WEB-115 Final Project</title>\n</head>\n<body>`);
      myText += `<div id="firstName">${fName}</div>`;
      myText += (lName);
      myText += (pName);
      myText += (eAddress);
      myText += (phoneNum);
      myText += (stateAdd);
      myText += (cityAdd);
      myText += (zipCode);
      myText += (about);
      myText += (schoolStart);
      myText += (schoolEnd);
      myText += (schoolName);
      myText += (degreeType);
      myText += (fieldStudy);
      myText += (jStart);
      myText += (jEnd);
      myText += (jobDetails);
      myText += (mySkills);
      myText += (webPage);
      myText += ("</body>\n</html>");

      flyWindow = window.open('about:blank', 'myPop', 'width=400,height=200,left=200,top=200');
      flyWindow.document.write(myText);
      myFunctionToSetCenterFirstName();
    }
    // Create global variable flyWindow to set style by a javascript function
    var flyWindow;
    // Then set style by this function
    function myFunctionToSetCenterFirstName() {
      let fName = flyWindow.document.getElementById("firstName");
      fName.style.textAlign = "center";
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Successful people are patient people, believe it!

Comment: Note to this line of my code, a bit difference with your code: myText += \`<div id="firstName">${fName}</div>\`;

Comment: Thank you so much! I've seen this as a solution but I was not sure where to place it to make it work. This make so much sense!